# hash file location on Mac?

Tags: macos, hash, passwords

If I encrypt a file as file1 using openssl, where is the hash of that password stored?

No matter what I Google, the closest I get are instructions to enable root and navigate to /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users directory. Unless I'm just not recognizing it, I am unable to find anything that looks like what I want in there.

Comment: I suggest you go to the help section and read the topics about asking good questions. There is no chance anybody will have any clue about what you're asking for.

Comment: The first line says it all. Where are the hashes of passwords saved?

Comment: The hash of what password?

Comment: a file I encrypt as file1.txt using openssl. A password is created and must be stored on my system somewhere to be compared to when I try to open the file later.

Comment: So show your code. If you are doing password-based encryption neither the password nor it's hash are stored anywhere unless *you* store them.

Comment: See the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question. Seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (i.e. that it's about encrypting a file with `openssl enc -ciphername` or the shorthand `openssl ciphername`), then the answer is: the hash is not stored *anywhere*.

What happens is that the password (and salt) are run through a hash function to derive an encryption key, and that key is used to encrypt the contents of the file. The key (i.e. the hash) is then discarded.

When you go to decrypt the file, it runs the password you entered and the salt (stored in the file) through the same hash function, and attempts to use that to decrypt the file's contents. If the password is the same as that used to encrypt, you get your original file back. If the password is different, you get back gibberish. openssl *might* be able to tell it's gibberish if the padding doesn't make sense, but it might not. As the man page says:

> All the block ciphers normally use PKCS#5 padding also known as
>   standard block padding: this allows a rudimentary integrity or
>   password check to be performed. However since the chance of random
>   data passing the test is better than 1 in 256 it isn't a very good
>   test.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. I misunderstood how that worked and in all my Googling, I didn't find an explanation like this. 

I learned something new. Thanks again.